# why is bundle & minifier 2015 do not generate CSS source map files?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass, source-maps, web-essentials

Its on Visual studio 2015, since web essential updated to 2015.2 version that provide Bundle & minifier to support bundle and minification. However setting in bundleconfig.json works for source map in Javascript files, but do not provide support for CSS? Also do not compile SASS to source map file, too. I have tried so many ways to add the source file in css. Anyone, please help.

```
[
 {
    "outputFileName": "Styles/room-ready-bundle.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Content/styles/bootstrap-overwrite.css",
      "Content/styles/controls.css",
      "Content/styles/layout.css",
      "Content/styles/home.css"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mappings": "AAAAA,SAASA,kBAAmB,CAACC"
  },
  {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outputFileName": "JavaScripts/test-bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "Scripts/jquery.equalheights.min.js",
      "Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js",
      "Scripts/Nav.js",
      "Scripts/jquery.arrange.form.js",
      "Scripts/jquery.time.popup.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because unfortunately it's not supported yet

> Source maps are supported for JavaScript minification only at this time.

see:
https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier